# Using .load() after .detach() and .append() not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having troubles using a .load() method in my Javascript, it works fine on page load, but after I detach the corresponding element and append it again, the method is not working anymore. You can see my code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function () {

    var div = $('#exhibitions');
    var max = @Model.Total;
    var count = 0;

    div.find('.show-more').click(function () {
        div.find('.more-exhi').hide().load('@Url.Action("Exhibitions", "Exhibition")', { year: $(this).attr('data-year') } ).fadeIn('1500');
        div.find('.show-less').show();
        $('.more-exhi').attr('class', 'less-exhi');
        count++;
        if (count == max) {
            div.find('.show-more').hide().detach().hide();
        }
    });

    div.find('.show-less').click(function () {
        var button = div.find('button.show-more').detach();

        div.find('.more-exhi').fadeOut('1500');
        div.find('.less-exhi').fadeOut('1500');
        div.find('.show-less').hide();
        div.find('.holder').append(button);
        div.find('.show-more').attr('data-year', '@DateTime.Now.Year');
    });

})();
</script>
```

I used the debugger, but as far as debugging goes: There are no errors and everything should work fine. However when I step over the part of the code (line 10) where new content is being loaded, nothing is being added to the page (however I am sure that the load() method has valid content calls).

I know the event works, as the other methods in this function are still working correctly. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Don't detach and re-attach elements, just hide and show them.

Comment: @Barmar I cannot use hide and show in this circumstance.

Comment: @KevinVoorn: Whyever not? (Although I don't think the `detach`/`append` is actually the problem.)

Comment: Since you're changing classes dynamically, you should use event delegation to bind your handlers.

Comment: @Barmar: I don't see any handlers on the elements whose classes change.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, misread. Confused `.show-more` with `.more-exhi`.

Comment: You're loading the new content into a hidden DIV. So it should be in the DOM, but won't be displayed by the browser.

Comment: `.hide().detach().hide()`? Just in case the first hide doesn't work?

Comment: The javascript you see above is just a sample code, not the whole code we use. Because of other parts in our project we are unable to use hide() and show(). Anyway, the issue has been resolved already and was caused by some left-over code (see answer below).

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for pointing that out, I removed the second hide() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you process a click, you completely replace all classes on any element that has the `more-exhi` class with `less-exhi` by doing this:

```
$('.more-exhi').attr('class', 'less-exhi');
```

...and then never put `more-exhi` back elsewhere. So on subsequent clicks, this line becomes a no-op:

```
div.find('.more-exhi').hide().load('@Url.Action("Exhibitions", "Exhibition")', { year: $(this).attr('data-year') } ).fadeIn('1500');
```

...since `div.find('.more-exhi')` won't find any elements.

Comment: It worked, not sure why I didn't catch this small mistake. It was some left-over code from the first version of the project which I missed during the transition. Thanks!